# readonly field not initialized - no warning

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, .net-5, compiler-bug

I have the following class with an obviously uninitialized readonly field. This compiles fine with no erros or warnings:

```
public class Test
{
    readonly string s;

    public string GetString() => this.s.ToLower();
}
```

The fun part comes now. When I explicitly declare the field as private (which is default anyway, isn't it?) I now get a warning as I would expect:

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly string s;

    public string GetString() => this.s.ToLower();
}
```

warning CS0649: Field 'Test.s' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Is this a Bug?

Iam using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.9.3.

Comment: You can easily get a Microsoft programmer roll their eyeballs with Help > Send Feedback.

Comment: Without testing, just guessing, what happens if you try to instantiate a `Test`? And what if you instantiate it with an initializer? `new Test() { s = "fnord" }`

Comment: When all else fails, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

Comment: @NicholasHunter That's not really what the question is about.

Comment: @NicholasHunter Or at most, it's related, but doesn't directly address the question.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede it addresses the question of what is the default access modifier of a field, which OP seems to think is relevant.

Comment: @NicholasHunter It's clearly relevant. The access modifier does alter the requirement to explicitly initialize a readonly field. The question is why, and exactly what are the rules?

Comment: I also have Community 16.9.3 and I can confirm this behavior.

Comment: ...and now I can't. When I changed your `GetString` method to a property `public string S => s;` it started telling me `s` was unused. Then, finally, it gave me the expected warning. This could be one of those things where VS loses its mind for a while and then corrects itself.

Comment: The implicitly accessibility modifier is indeed `private`. This seems like a static analysis bug.